# Grails different version project in same work-space

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using **STS**(Spring source tool Suite).Is it possible to have different versions Grails project in same work-space.
When i tried, they always upgraded to a more recent version of Grails.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible as long as both versions of grails use the same version of groovy (multiple grails installs are allowed, but only one groovy install at a time).

In your project -> Properties -> Grails, click "Enable project-specific settings".  And choose the version of grails that you need.